# How to create an NpgSqlParameterArray in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSql. I have method as below, I need to create an  parameter array and pass it to below  method. How can I do that please suggest me

```
    internal static DataTable ExecuteParamerizedSelectcommand(String CommandName,CommandType cmdType,NpgsqlParameter[] param)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(constr);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
            cmd.CommandText = CommandName;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

            if(con.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

             using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da= new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                table = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(table);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch {
            throw;
        }
        return table;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You create NpgsqlParameter  like this:

```
NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("your_parameter_name", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text);
p.value = your_parameter_name;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

if you need pass NpgsqlParameter[] as parameter. first of all you should form your NpgsqlParameter array correctly.

for example: 
create new variable:

```
new NpgsqlParameter[2]{ 
        new NpgsqlParameter{ ParameterName="your_parameter_name1", Value=val1},
        new NpgsqlParameter{ ParameterName="your_parameter_name2", Value=val2}
        }
```

then pass it as param.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param)
```

have you got any errors?

Comment: thanks for your reponse,your way is not suits my requirement please look at my question I have changed it ,you might get cleared with my question

Comment: yes sir i did but i have an error like    'System.NullReferenceException'   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  In my Helper method  things i did as shown in below comment

Comment: String query = "select * from t where name=:value1 and psd=:value2";                                     NpgsqlParameter[] param = new NpgsqlParameter[]
 {                                                                                                            new NpgsqlParameter{ ParameterName="value1",Value="ss"},         new NpgsqlParameter{ ParameterName="value2", Value="1234"}
        };                                                                   postgreHelper.ExecuteNonQuerywithReturnStatement(query, CommandType.Text, param); please help me